# Rails3 mailer with image_tag ignoring host

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, path, mailer

I've got a Rails3 mailer layout that include images.

This ones are used like :

```
image_tag("emails/top.gif", :width => "700", :height => "10", :alt => "")
```

As of Rails 2, this images included the host and produced the expected result. However, since Rails3 the `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` seems to be ignored.

Is there anything I'm missing?

**Update**

my config/environment/development.rb include:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.tld' }
```

Comment: Answered by wmoxam in #rubyonrails : Needs to use config.action_mailer.asset_host in your environment config file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Needs to use `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://mysite.com'` in your environment config file

*Credits: wmoxam in #rubyonrails*